Getting NAN p-value from logistic regression!
I'm trying to find p-values for coefficients of a logistic regression using MATLAB fitglm function, but I keep getting NAN values. I suspect this caused by the INF output of logit function. So I modified the response values from 0 and 1 to 0.01 and 0.99, but this didn't work.
Next I attempted to calculate the logit manually and apply simple linear regression, but I was not sure which distribution to use. I tried the binomial distribution, but still returned the NAN p-values. I, Also tried normal distribution which returned finite values, but it doesn't seem to be right!
So how can I handle this problem?
I have about 290 samples, which I kept 40 samples aside for validation, so 250 remained for training. The features consist of various features extracted from EEG signal and there are two classes with nearly same probability (0.4 and 0.6).
mdl = fitglm(features, response, 'link', 'logit', 
    'Distribution', 'binomial', 'CategoricalVars', 
    CategoricalVars);

Estimated Coefficients:
                            
                   __________    ________    __________    ______

                     Estimate      SE           tStat       pValue              
    (Intercept)        1.8993      2.3721       0.80067     NaN  
    x1                 -2.197     0.73318       -2.9966     NaN  
    x2                -1.3026     0.94587       -1.3771     NaN  
    x3               -0.20243     0.96988      -0.20872     NaN  
    x4                0.35804     0.86712       0.41291     NaN  
    x5               -0.29205     0.67105      -0.43521     NaN  
    x6                 1.5936      1.0911        1.4605     NaN  
    x7                -1.2516     0.66291        -1.888     NaN  
    x8                -1.1029      1.0365       -1.0641     NaN  
    x9                 3.9931      0.7776        5.1352     NaN  
    x10            -0.0062073     0.91793    -0.0067622     NaN  
    x11               0.15274      0.7048       0.21671     NaN  
    x12              -0.28497     0.97436      -0.29247     NaN  
    x13                1.6847     0.95336        1.7671     NaN  
    x14                4.7506      1.1674        4.0692     NaN  
    x15               0.61685      1.0558       0.58426     NaN  
    x16              -0.91512      1.0008      -0.91437     NaN  
    x17               -0.9848      1.0112      -0.97391     NaN  
    x18               -2.1549      1.0969       -1.9644     NaN  
    x19               -1.5119      1.0367       -1.4583     NaN  
    x20               -1.0072     0.69128        -1.457     NaN  
    x21               -3.0984     0.76139       -4.0695     NaN  
    x22              -0.25906     0.99083      -0.26146     NaN  
    x23               0.47229      0.9586       0.49268     NaN  
    x24               0.91123     0.92178       0.98856     NaN  
    x25               0.10853     0.99246       0.10936     NaN  
    x26               -3.1111      1.0167       -3.0602     NaN  
    x27              0.096781      1.1659      0.083013     NaN  
    x28              -0.21485     0.68659      -0.31292     NaN  
    x29             -0.040434    0.015808       -2.5579     NaN  
    x30             -0.033061    0.016251       -2.0344     NaN  
    x31_1            0.092989     0.32625       0.28502     NaN  


can you share any code illustrating the issue?

@JohnMadden I've included the results.

There seem to be two problems here, one statistical and one in the software. As your display includes t statistics, the problem with NaN for their p values might be in the software not knowing how many degrees of freedom to use in the calculation. Check the manual.

The statistical issue: if you have a binary outcome then you should not be using linear regression anyway. It sounds like you have too few members of the minority class to fit a model with 31 predictors, leading to perfect separation. Please edit the question to say more about the data, in particular how many cases have the minority-class outcome and what you are trying to learn from the model. I suspect that any reliable model will need to be simpler.

@EdM the number of predictors is not the problem, it doesn't work with single predictor either. Also i could add some feature selection before the regression or use LASSO algorithm.

@EDM it seems to be the software problem, Especially when i choose the binomial distribution!!

First, you have too few cases for reliably building and testing a model on separate subsets. See this web page for an introduction to the issues. With this number of cases you can instead build the model on the entire data set and then evaluate the reliability of the modeling process by repeating the process on multiple bootstrapped samples from the data.
Second, you might be able to get away with a linear-regression probability model with your class probabilities close to 0.5, but there's no need to take that risk. There are ways to deal with the problems you found in your logistic regression. The rest of this answer is based on using logistic regression or another type of regression suitable for binary outcomes.
Third, a rule of thumb to avoid overfitting in binary-outcome regressions, in Section 4.4 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies (RMS), suggests that you shouldn't try to fit more than about 14 unpenalized regression coefficients to your data. Your 31 are more than twice that many, putting you at risk of overfitting.
You could use data reduction methods to combine your predictors into a lower number for the model; see Section 4.7 and Chapter 8 of RMS. Alternatively, you could penalize the coefficients to minimize overfitting. LASSO is one form of penalization, but its choice of which predictors to keep can vary a lot from sample to sample. You might be better off with ridge regression, which keeps all predictors while penalizing their coefficients, or the LASSO-ridge combination in elastic net.
Fourth, with multiple predictors in a binary-outcome model you do run a risk of perfect separation, which is what I suspect drew you away from logistic regression at first. In that case, the Wald tests for p-values that are routinely reported for individual coefficients don't work. You nevertheless can use a profile likelihood to put a confidence limit on one side of a troublesome coefficient estimate. Penalization with ridge regression can both minimize overfitting and avoid perfect separation. An early penalization method (Firth's method) was designed specifically to deal with perfect separation.
Fifth, although MATLAB provides superb facilities for signal processing and such, my sense is that its support for statistical testing can leave something to be desired. There can be hidden assumptions in default settings that might make sense if you already know the underpinnings of the tests but that can lead you astray otherwise. See this recent question, in which MATLAB function names and default settings led to the wrong choice of test to run. I think that you will end up with fewer problems and find it easier to get help if, after you've used MATLAB for EEG signal processing, you use R (freely available) or SAS (if you need a commercial package) for downstream statistical analysis.
